# Username is not a member of the user table facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

For last few years I was using FQL of Facebook in which i gathered data about last comments by fans on one of my pages. To do that I was forced to use 2 tables joins. I could do that with fql.multiquery help.

Small code of this:

```
$query1 = "SELECT source_id, post_id, created_time , actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = ".$page_id." AND actor_id != ".$page_id." 
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 3";        
$query2 = "SELECT username, uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid in (SELECT actor_id FROM #query1)";

$multiQuery = array
(
   "query1" => $query1,
   "query2" => $query2,
);

$param = array(       
   'method' => 'fql.multiquery',       
   'queries' => $multiQuery,       
   'callback' => '');       
$queryresults = $facebook->api($param);
```

Today i got the error "username is not a member of the user table Facebook API".

- I have searched for Facebook user table fields ( maybe they have changed ).
- Tried 'SELECT *' - other error ( not allowed )

On Facebook i have found that soon ( in April ), API 2.0 will be shut down. And 2.1 FQL is deprecated.

I want to fix this in easy way.

Any information will be helpful.

Comment: I think they have removed the username field. You can use userid instead

Comment: Nope. userid or user_id not working. Same error: "userid is not a member of the user table". Anyways i already wrote solution i have choosed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct that the `username` field is deprecated with the use of the Graph API v2.0 and higher. I'd recommend to use the `uid` field instead.

The problems are that you're using the wrong endpoint with your FQL query. `fql.multiquery` resolves to the old REST API, which will be deprecated on April 30th, 2015.

The regular "new" FQL endpoint in the Graph API is `/fql?q={query}`, and you can use the Batch API to trigger multiple requests at once. If you've got a v2.0 app, you can use FQL until August 7th, 2016.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests

Comment: I have tried id as you wrote. Result is same: "id is not a member of the user table."

Comment: Tobi. You edited your post. And i had uid in my selection already. The problem is that i need username to show images liks this:
https://graph.facebook.com/igloro/picture?width=100&height=100 . Where igloro is my username ( or other person's )

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The username field was removed in API v2.0 and later. So there is no way for you to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution for now... Thanks to Tobi, i choosed /fql?q= method
so here is my code if someone will need.

```
function getcontents($query,$access_token)
{
  $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=".urlencode($query);
  $url .= "&access_token=".$access_token;
  $content = file_get_contents($url);
  $content = json_decode($content);

  return $content;
}
```

//--------

```
$query1 = "SELECT source_id, post_id, created_time , actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = ".$page_id." AND actor_id != ".$page_id." 
ORDER BY created_time DESC
LIMIT 3
";       

$content = getcontents($query1,$access_token);     

$actor_ids = array();
foreach ($content->data as $key => $value) 
{
  $data[$value->actor_id] = $value;
  $actor_ids[] = $value->actor_id;  
}

$query2 = "SELECT username, uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid in (".implode(",",$actor_ids).")";  
$content = getcontents($query2,$access_token); 

foreach ($content->data as $key => $value) 
{
   $data[$value->uid] = array_merge((array) $data[$value->uid],(array) $value);
}
```

Works for now...